# Why is blender rendering entire tile?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

As you'll see, my blender is strangely (i think) rendering the image as an entire tile and not a "one by one tile".

I'm using GPU (if using both GPU and CPU it shows the tiles). I'm also using Auto Tile Size plugin, but even when i check the 64px box it renders the entire tile.

My assumption is that render is not properly using my GPU, as i had to format my pc and install windows, then got a blue screen error and had to re-install windows using repair option (so i think the drivers doubled (?)).

Does anyone have an answer or assumption?

[image]

Comment: Cycles has an option for progressive render, it's in *Cycles Render Properties > Performance > Tiles > [_] Progressive Refine*. Maybe you have checked this checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it can be the progressive refine setting "on": Progressive rendering will make a tile as big as your image -> render time will be long

[image]